# Show ProgressDialog while image downloading

Tags: android, image, progressdialog

my application have a **download feature** Take some time to download image for that i'm trying to add `ProgressDialog` while image downloading. `ProgressDialog` It never appears please help me

this my code for save image:

```
private String saveImage(Bitmap image) {
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Pop.this);
    pd.setMessage("Downloading ...");
    pd.show();
    String savedImagePath = null;
    String imageFileName = "vapor"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".png";
    File storageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    + "/vaporwave");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        success = storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
        savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Add the image to the system gallery
        galleryAddPic(savedImagePath);
        Toast.makeText(Pop.this, "IMAGE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pd.dismiss();
    }
    return savedImagePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use some background task like `AsyncTask`, you should not do complex task on your UI thread.(otherwise your UI will luck until task done , so your `progressDialog` never show)

you can read about AsyncTask [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

for example in async :

1) show your progressDialog on `onPreExecute`

2) and dismiss it in `onPostExecute`

3) and do your work(saving image) in `doInBackground` (return type in this method will pass to `onPostExecute`)

```
public class saveImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String>{
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(Pop.this);
        pd.setMessage("Downloading ...");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        Bitmap image = params[0];
        String savedImagePath = null;
        String imageFileName = "vapor"+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".png";
        File storageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                        + "/vaporwave");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            success = storageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        if (success) {
            File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
            savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
            try {
                OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Add the image to the system gallery
            galleryAddPic(savedImagePath);
            Toast.makeText(Pop.this, "IMAGE SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        return savedImagePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //s is your savedImagePath
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

you can call this task like this:

```
    new saveImage().execute(yourBitmap);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i have a problem with `Bitmap Image` in `image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);` also i have a problem with            ` return savedImagePath;` i put all my code in on doInBackground

Comment: I change my answer base on your code, see updated saveImage task.